# How to configure Dispatcher flush replication agent and farm files for multiple domains having webpages in single AEM instance

Tags: apache, caching, aem, dispatcher

I have a website running on AEM server. The requirement is to launch a new website. So I created new farm files and added a new virtual host. I have problem with caching. So the root directory is /mnt/var/www/html. To separate two domains, created two sub directories as /mnt/var/www/html/domainA and /mnt/.../domainB. Some pages are caching in wrong directory meaning domain A pages to domain B pages. Meaning hitting one of the other farm files.

There is only one default flush agent in publish configured with IP. So I thought to rename the existing default flush agent with domain A(instead of IP). Also create a new agent for domain B(http://domainname:80/dispatcher/invalidate.cache) But this agent is failing saying domain not found 404.

Please share your knowledge if I'm missing anything or configuring it wrong.

Comment: Are you using sling maps? Dispatcher flish agents resolve resources using sling maps. Also what's your stat level on dispatcher?

Comment: Yes, I'm using sling mapping. It was 0. I tried changing it to 2. But I see same.